# How to design API's to store client files on external storage system

Tags: amazon-s3, api-design

Suppose we have a client application(mobile app or web app etc) working with a our back-end services.T he client wants to store some object(like profile photo or a PDF etc). Now suppose that we want to store this data on the servers of a third party storage provider(like `aws S3` etc). What is the best practice to do so?

To achieve this goal I have two ideas:

1. Our client sends the object directly to the back-end (maybe in a base64 format).
   The back-end software takes care of storing this data on the cloud and saving the path of that data on to its own database for later usage, it then informs the client that the operation has succeeded or not.
2. The client informs the back-end that it wants to store some file. Our software generates a unique `Secure URL` with limited expiration time and sends it to the client. The client can now save that specific file to the cloud and then inform the back-end. Then the back-end makes sure the file is saved on updates its own database for later usage.

Recently I have encounter such a situation and don't know which method to take. Personally  I think the second method is more *elegant and idiomatic* but it comes at the cost of more complexity and network calls. What method should I choose and If there is other patterns for implementing this kind of task what are they?